# Como usar o vector para armazenar uma classe?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, vector

Exemplo:

```
 class Nome
    {private:
             string nome;
        public:
            Nome(string nome);
            virtual void exibirNome() =0;

    };
class SobreNome: public Nome
    {private:
             string nome;
        public:
            SobreNome(string nome, string sobre_nome): Nome(nome) ;

            void exibirNome();

    };
```

No `main`

```
vector<Nome> *nome;
 Nome *n  = new SobreNome("João", "Alves");
nome->push_back(n);
```

pois assim não estou conseguindo.

> error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Nome"

Qual a maneira correta?

Comment: Coloque o código de forma mais completa pra gente ver.

Comment: Eu dei uma resposta supondo algumas coisas, com o código completo eu poderia dar uma resposta melhor ainda.

Comment: @bigown código é assim mesmo

Comment: Na verdade eu tive que completar ele para conseguir testar. Fiz um funcionando, outro com o ajuste pedido no comentário na resposta e outro usando gerenciamento automático de memória, que é o mais correto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O código tem alguns problemas, não vou consertar tudo, mas vou permitir que pelo menos ele seja compilado:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Nome {
    protected:
        string nome;
    public:
        Nome(string _nome) {
            nome = _nome;
        }
        virtual void exibirNome() = 0;
};
class SobreNome : public Nome {
    string sobre_nome;
    public:
        SobreNome(string nome, string _sobre_nome) : Nome(nome) {
            sobre_nome = _sobre_nome;
        }
        void exibirNome() {
            cout << nome << " " << sobre_nome;
        }
};

int main() {
    vector<Nome*> *nome = new vector<Nome*>;
    Nome *n = new SobreNome("João", "Alves");
    nome->push_back(n);
    nome->at(0)->exibirNome();
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/R0gl7f). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qwhgtwvx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/AddObject.cpp).

Pra usar o acesso pelo operador de índice tem que fazer isto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Nome {
    protected:
        string nome;
    public:
        Nome(string _nome) {
            nome = _nome;
        }
        virtual void exibirNome() = 0;
};
class SobreNome : public Nome {
    string sobre_nome;
    public:
        SobreNome(string nome, string _sobre_nome) : Nome(nome) {
            sobre_nome = _sobre_nome;
        }
        void exibirNome() {
            cout << nome << " " << sobre_nome;
        }
};

int main() {
    vector<Nome*> nome;
    Nome *n = new SobreNome("João", "Alves");
    nome.push_back(n);
    nome[0]->exibirNome();
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uK6T6o). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vlidxcnw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/AddIndexer.cpp).

Ainda não é a hora mas depois procure usar [*smart pointers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) no lugar de ponteiros brutos. Este código é simples e não gera dano, mas em código real isto vazaria memória. C++ não é Java, você tem que gerenciar a memória.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Nome {
    protected:
        string nome;
    public:
        Nome(string _nome) {
            nome = _nome;
        }
        virtual void exibirNome() = 0;
};
class SobreNome : public Nome {
    string sobre_nome;
    public:
        SobreNome(string nome, string _sobre_nome) : Nome(nome) {
            sobre_nome = _sobre_nome;
        }
        void exibirNome() {
            cout << nome << " " << sobre_nome;
        }
};

int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<Nome>> nome;
    nome.emplace_back(new SobreNome("João", "Alves"));
    nome[0]->exibirNome();
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pg6nPf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/msxfgiol-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/AddSmartPointer.cpp).

Comment: como chamar o método exibir Nome ? assim  não está dando certo `nome[0]->exibirNome();`

Comment: foi mal mesmo, só não coloquei todo código pois cabei fechando sem salvar, nas próximas vezes faço certo

Answer (score 2):

Você está atribuindo a classe ao seu ponteiro de vetor, assim você não terá um vetor e sim uma classe alocada no ponteiro. Você deve criar a instancia do ponteiro antes de tudo.

```
class C{
    C(){
        std::cout << "instanciada" << std::endl;
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<C> class_vec; // cria um vetor de classes C
    C my_class;
    class_vec.push_back(my_class); // adiciona a classe na lista

    my_class = class_vec[0]; // retorna a primeira classe inserida na lista
}
```

Você também pode fazer o processo usando ponteiros:

```
#include <vector>

class C{};

using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<C*> *class_vec = new vector<C*>(); // cria um vetor de classes C
    C *my_class = new C();
    class_vec->push_back(my_class); // adiciona a classe na lista

}
```