# Operador & e * nas funções

Tags: c, c++, funções, ponteiro, operadores

Qual o significado desse & na frente do matriz (minha função só funciona com &, estou sobrecarregando cout<<(matriz1 + matriz2))

E o significado também do * na frente do void?!
Grato

```
matriz& operator + (matriz b){

    for(int i = 0; i < b.data.size(); i++)  

        for(int j = 0; j < b.data[i].size();j++)    
            b.data[i][j] += this->data[i][j];   
    }

    return b;           
    }



void * func(){
cout<<"Teste"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Dê uma pesquisada nas perguntas que já existem aqui. Esta aqui, por exemplo, contém uma explicação bem extensa sobre ponteiros e referências, que são a sua dúvida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56470/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ponteiro-e-refer%C3%AAncia

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 7):

<sub>A pergunta dá a impressão que está aprendendo de um jeito pouco estruturado e isto não costuma dar certo. É importante entender todos os conceitos, saber porque cada coisa existe e porque usar. A pergunta parece remeter a isso, mas a forma como ela originou é preocupante. Tentar fazer alguma coisa pra ver se funciona não ajuda o entendimento. Um livro de qualidade é recomendado para ir passo a passo.</sub>

Para entender o básico sobre o assunto tem a pergunta já mencionada pelo C. E. Gesser em comentário.

Nesse contexto esses símbolos não são operadores, eles fazem parte do nome do tipo. Vamos dizer que se não os usassem e a linguagem preferisse ter nomes de tipos explícitos por extenso, seria algo assim: `reference matriz` e `pointer void`.

Note que isso nada tem a ver com a função ou o operador (que no fundo é uma função também. Por acaso estão sendo usados como retorno delas, mas isso é sobre o tipo de dados, que todo retorno de função deve ter. É só uma declaração de tipo a ser retornado.

Esses códigos são esquisitos, ou até mesmo errados. No primeiro a sintaxe não faz sentido algum. O segundo nem está retornando alguma coisa, menos ainda um ponteiro, não faz sentido. Justamente é isso que me preocupa na pergunta. Foram colocados códigos aleatórios, não se aprende direito assim (não vou colocar o certo porque não é o foco da pergunta, mas [pode ser visto no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15080135/221800), em [outra pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2464150/221800)). Enfim tem erro demais aí.

A referência só existe em C++. Ele indica que o conteúdo ali será um ponteiro gerenciado de alguma forma (um ponteiro é um mecanismo muito simples tem mais informações em *links* aqui, leia para entender como a referência sempre acaba usando esse mecanismo). Na prática há garantias que ele não será nulo (a não ser em código sem sentido) e não pode-se manipulá-lo como o ponteiro permite. Mais detalhes em [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101).

O [`void*` é usado para indicar que ali poderá vir qualquer tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97138/101) já que C é uma linguagem fracamente tipada e interpreta o que tem ali de acordo com a conveniência do programador. Um [exemplo do uso de `void*`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137773/101) pode ser encontrado em outra pergunta. Esta técnica é considerada obsoleta em C++ para a maioria dos efeitos (mas não para todos, se quiser gastar um tempo tem alguns exemplos nos comentários, mesmo tendo alguns casos não invalida que ele não deve ser usado na maioria dos casos, ficaria longo listar tudo o que pode ser usado no lugar e não é o foco da pergunta).

Em geral ponteiros brutos devem ser evitados tanto quanto dá em C++. Eles podem ser substituídos por simples referências ou por [ponteiros inteligentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83886/101) ([exemplo de uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120243/101)).

Leia mais em:

- [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101)
- [Qual a finalidade da função free()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43766/101)
- [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)

Comment: A conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105443/discussion-on-answer-by-maniero-operador-e-nas-funcoes). Se alguém quiser ler ou acrescentar algo, basta clicar no link.