# Erro no printf do C

Tags: c, printf

O erro em questão em uma *flag* que deveria supostamente estar correta, segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

char var[50]=" Write Once Bug Everywere ";

int i,cont=0;

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    if(var[i]==' '){
        cont++;
    }
}

printf("Existem %d espaços em branco",&cont);   
}
```

Quando passo o mouse por cima do erro no NetBeans ele me dá a seguinte dica:

> "Incompatibilidade do tipo de argumento "int*" e especificador de
>   conversão "d" ".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você mandando imprimir o endereço de `cont` já que usou o operador `&`. Se quer imprimir o contador, mande imprimi-lo e não outra informação. Se quisesse imprimir um ponteiro poderia usar `%p`. [Documentação de formatação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char var[50] = " Write Once Run Everywere ";
    int cont = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) if (var[i] == ' ') cont++;
    printf("Existem %d espaços em branco", cont);   
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/780Q4A). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dhffluva-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/PrintfMismatch.c).

Acredito que o engano ocorreu porque no [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf), costuma exigir o endereço. Isto ocorre porque você vai mudar o seu valor, então você passa o endereço da variável para a função saber onde colocar o que foi digitado. O `printf()` só vai usar o valor, não precisa pegar seu endereço.

[Leia mais sobre o operador e ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156278/101). C é bruto, tem que cuidar de tudo.

Todos os tipos podem ser acessado através do seu endereço. O tipo ponteiro obviamente já é um endereço e normalmente o *array* é acessando pelo seu endereço.

Você tem que ler a documentação da função para ver o que precisa passar para ela.

Comment: Obrigado! quais tipos que podem ter seus valores acessados pelo endereço de memória?

Comment: @William.Andrade editei e dei mais detalhes.

Comment: Obrigado cara, agente sai de uma linguagem aonde tudo isso é gerenciado e acaba apanhando um pouco pra enteder.

Answer (score 7):

Troque

> printf("Existem %d espaços em branco",&cont);

por

```
printf("Existem %d espaços em branco",cont);
```

Ao utilizar o `&`, você tenta imprimir o **endereço da variável**, por isto o erro:

> incompatibilidade com **int***

`int*` é um ponteiro para inteiro, neste caso, o valor do endereço de memória que contém a variável `cont`.

Comment: Gostaria de poder colocar as duas respostas como certas obrigado por responder! :)