# Otimização de vários ifs em algo mais prático

Tags: c, string, loop, caracteres

Eu tenho uma *string* de caracteres alfabéticos:

```
char string[] = "aouihuiahsudasduihqmdoiqjnduiamsdoqnwuidamodkjwodkaposdj";
```

Quero percorrer ela toda e para cada caractere dela, dizer quantas vezes ele se repete na *string*.

#### Exemplo:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Quantidade{
   int qtd;
};

char string = 
"aouihuiahsudasduihqmdoiqjnduiamsdoqnwuidamodkjwodkaposdj";


int main(){
     struct Quantidade vetor[];

     for(i=0; i<strlen(string); i++{
        if(string[i] == 'a'){
            vetor[0].qtd++;    
        } 
        else if(string[i] == 'b'){
            vetor[1].qtd++;
        }
        ...
        else if(string[i] == 'z'){
             vetor[25].qtd++;
        }
     }

   return 0;
 }
```

Ao invés de usar 26 `if`s dentro do código, como eu posso fazer de forma mais otimizada?

Comment: Já ouviu falar em switch?

Comment: Sem criar uma estrutura de dados complexa demais, a solução mais simples é criar um *array* para cada opção e ir incrementando baseado em cálculo com o caractere. Só pode letras minúsculas? Aí o *array* terá 26 posições. verei se dou um jeito daqui a pouco.

Comment: pode ser também também, eu só gostaria de saber se tem outra lógica com loop para não ficar usando 26 ifs...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se só pode letras minúsculas pode fazer um *array* com 26 posições e ir guardando nelas de acordo com o que acha.

Em `*string - 'a'` é um cálculo para achar qual é a posição do *array*. Quase sempre dá para usar a matemática para ajudar simplificar algoritmos. Então pego o conteúdo apontado pelo ponteiro `string` que é o caractere daquele passo, ele será avaliado de acordo com a [tabela ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Então o `a` é código 97, não queremos isso, queremos 0, então é simples, subtraímos 97, mas pra ficar mais legível subtraímos o próprio `a` que vale 97. E se o caractere for `d`, não 100 - 97 dá 3, portanto o elemento usado será o quanto do *array*. Dá tudo certo.

Na hora de usar para restaurar o caractere tem que somar o 97 de novo.

Assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *string = "aouihuiahsudasduihqmdoiqjnduiamsdoqnwuidamodkjwodkaposdj";
    int quantidade[26] = { 0 }; //inicializa todos elementos zerados
    for (; *string != '\0'; string++) { //termina quando chegar no nulo que é fim de string
        quantidade[*string - 'a']++; //incrementa conteúdo apontado por string - código 'a'
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        printf("%c => %d\n", i + 'a', quantidade[i]); //soma 'a' pra ter o caractere correto
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/9W4Uul). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pxiivgoy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/CountChars.c).

Se puder ter outros caracteres é só aumentar a quantidade de posições do *array* para caber todo e fazer a conta do caractere sempre usando o primeiro possível.

Isto não funciona se puder ter faixas de caracteres separadas. Este algoritmo só funciona para uma faixa única de qualquer tamanho.

Se quiser dá para filtrar os que estão com 0 para não imprimir na lista, isto é bem fácil.

Este algoritmo faz o mesmo que o da pergunta.

Mas se zerados nem puder estar no *array*, aí terá que criar uma estrutura mais complexa onde guarde o caractere e sua soma, só quando chegar pelo menos a 1. E terá que existir um algoritmo de busca nesse *array8 que poderá ser linear, logaritmo ou constante dependendo do quanto quer garantia de performance e da complexidade aceitável. É bem mais complicado fazer isto.

Note que eu [evitei o uso de `strlen()` que não é o mais adequado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101). Então avança com o ponteiro (`string++`) em cada caractere e verifica se [chegou no fim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101). Se tem dificuldade de ler isso veja os [operadores de ponteiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156278/101).

Quase fiz com `while`, acho que era o melhor neste caso.

Comment: Cara, era exatamente isso que eu queria. Apesar de eu não ter entendido a lógica ainda, vou até salvar no meu github também para futuras revisões. Brigadão @bigown :D

Comment: Depois eu explico melhor :)

Comment: Muito boa a lógica, como sempre; a única coisa que faria diferente seria criar um segundo ponteiro para percorrer a _string_, já que nos casos reais você provavelmente vai querer manter uma referência ao princípio dela para usá-la novamente...

Comment: @Wtrmute eu pensei em fazer isso, para um exercício tá bom assim, em um código real de fato precisaria.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>   // strlen()
//#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_ALPHA 26
struct Quantidade{
   int qtd;
};

//char string =
//"aouihuiahsudasduihqmdoiqjnduiamsdoqnwuidamodkjwodkaposdj";
char string[] =
"aouihuiahsudasduihqmdoiqjnduiamsdoqnwuidamodkjwodkaposdj";

int main(){
     //struct Quantidade vetor[];
     struct Quantidade vetor[ NUM_ALPHA ];

     for( int i=0; i<NUM_ALPHA; i++ )
     {
         vetor[ i ].qtd = 0;  // initialize
     }

     // for(i=0; i<strlen(string); i++{
     for( size_t i=0; i<strlen(string); i++ )
     {
        //if(string[i] == 'a'){
        //    vetor[0].qtd++;
        //}
        //else if(string[i] == 'b'){
        //    vetor[1].qtd++;
        //}
        //...
        //else if(string[i] == 'z'){
        //     vetor[25].qtd++;
        //}
        vetor[ string[i] - 'a' ].qtd++;
     }

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado,  se, array of 26

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, O OP queria usar uma estrutura

Comment: entendi. Eu havia focado mais no problema (excesso de `if`s), então acabei ignorando esse detalhe. Vou remover meus comentários depois de passar um tempo no cone da vergonha