# Como guardar os elementos distintos que ocorrem em outro vetor?

Tags: c

No vetor abaixo de 300 elementos, preciso guardar os elementos distintos que ocorrem em outro vetor chamado valores.
Já depois tenho que registrar quantas vezes o i-ésimo valor do vetor valores ocorre no primeiro vetor.
Comecei a fazer o code do vetor de 300 valores mas depois não sei fazer a partir daí, agradeço pela atenção

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    void lernumeros(int A[]){
        for(int i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {
        printf("\nDigiite um valor qualquer positivo:\n");
            scanf("%d", &A[i]);
            if(i < 0){ 
                printf("Numeros Negativos não são permitidos!");
                break;
                }
            }
    }





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não é todo compilador de C que interpreta corretamente funções declaradas dentro de funções. Também posso observar que você está pegando o intervalo fechado de `[0,300]`, o que dá um total de 301 elementos; deixe o final do intervalo aberto: `[0,300)`

Comment: Também, para verificar o número digitado, não verifique por `i`, mas por `A[i]`

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217720/64969

Comment: Os elementos precisam estar no vetor único na mesma ordem que no vetor original? Porque o meu primeiro reflexo é ordenar o vetor usando `qsort()` e depois ir copiando cada novo valor assim que ele mudar no vetor ordenado, copiando o mesmo de antemão para um _array_ de rascunho, caso necessário.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, primeiramente sugiro fortemente que você ajeite seu código e trabalhe com linked list, que é muito mais fácil. Mas vamos a resposta:

> No vetor abaixo de 300 elementos, preciso guardar os elementos
>   distintos que ocorrem em outro vetor chamado valores.

Se entendi bem, a cada elemento que vc insere, caso ele seja distinto dos já existentes quer guardar em outro vetor.. da pra fazer assim:

```
void Valor_Distinto (int Valor, *Valores) {
    int i = 0, valor = 0 ;
    while ( valorVetor != NULL ) {
        valorVetor = Valores[i];

        if(ValorVetor == Valor)
            return;

        i++;
    }

    if(Valores[i] != NULL){
        Valores[i] = Valor;
    }
}
```

Não testei o código, mas a lógica está aí. (possivelmente essa adição no vetor esteja errada).

> Já depois tenho que registrar quantas vezes o i-ésimo valor do vetor
>   valores ocorre no primeiro vetor.

Para isso é possível fazer outra função:

```
int Ocorrencias (int valor, *Vetor) {
    int i = 0, int ocorrencia = 0;    
    while (Vetor[i] != NULL) {

        if(Vetor[i] == valor)
            ocorrencias++;

        i++;
    }
    return ocorrencias;
}
```

É isso, espero que tenha ajudado.. note que nas duas funções a chamada do vetor provavelmente está errada, então vc vai precisar ajustar um pouco..

Dicas: Além de usar linked list, recomendo também que vc utilize MALLOC nesses vetores e não crie uma função dentro da main como no seu código.. Abraços!

Comment: Seu exemplo deu erro de compilação no ideone: [`expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token`](http://ideone.com/wjXF7R)

Comment: A abordagem de contagem faz uma passada para cada elemento do vetor de valores, portanto seu algoritmo tem tempo quadrático. Dependendo de como seja validado o código, pode não passar na validação por ser pouco performático

Comment: O problema de compilação se dá porque, ao contrário da definição de múltiplas variáveis locais, a definição de parâmetros não pode ter o tipo elidido; então se pode dizer `int a, b;`, mas não `int func(int a, b);`, por exemplo.