# Code::Blocks não imprime o valor do ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro, codeblocks

Desenvolvi um código em C com o objetivo de imprimir o valor e o endereço da variável x utilizando um ponteiro p, mas o Code::Blocks não imprime os valores.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    int main()
    {
    int x=2;
    int *p;
    p = &x;

    printf("O valor de X e: %p\n", *p);

    printf("O valor de X e: %d\n", p);

    return(0);

    }
```

Comment: Ele "não imprime os valores" ou "não imprime os valores que você esperava"? São coisas bem distintas, então poderia esclarecer?

Comment: Ele não imprime nenhum valo

Comment: @Anne é melhor colocar qual o erro que o codeblocks está a exibir e se possivel um print

Comment: @Fábio Morais acho que entendi porque ele não está retornando nenhum valor porque a variável x não foi atribuída a nenhum valor por isso não retornava nada. Atribui o valor 2 na variável x ele retornou o endereço da memória e o valor 00000002, mas quando eu mudo o valor para 12 por exemplo ele continua devolvendo o valor 2. Tentei usar o fflush(stdin) mas não consegui resolver

Comment: Em vez de %p use o %d, pois ao fazer o printf de `*p` vai imprimir o valor do x. Limpar o buffer nesse caso é irrelevante

Comment: Essa pergunta está muito confusa, isso está bem, 'c' é 12 em hexadecimal....

Comment: Você não pode mudar a pergunta, as pessoas já responderam o que tinha sido perguntado invalidando as respostas. Acho melhor ver o [tour], aqui não é um é fórum, a edição não é para mudar o conteúdo, apenas consertar algum problema ou dar informação adicional, o que tem na pergunta agora é a minha resposta. Se tem outra dúvida em relação à resposta dada faça um pergunta nova, não altere a mesma. Coloquei na resposta que funciona como esperado e as informações extras não estão batendo. Por isso eu reverti para o estado original.

Answer (score 1):

Não use `conio.h`, ainda que neste caso nem precise. E se estiver uma IDE com compilador ruim (Dev-C++), pare de fazer isto. Alias o Code::Blocks não faz nada na execução do código mesmo, [entenda quem é quem na programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

Pelo que entendi o primeiro você quer imprimir o endereço da memória onde está o `X` já que usou `%p`, e o segundo quer imprimir o valor de `X`. Então tem que arrumar o texto para dar uma informação correta.

Aí um problema é que está invertido. `p` já é um endereço de memória, então é só usá-lo no primeiro. O segundo quer o valor e pegá-lo indiretamente pela variável `p` que é um endereço, então agora tem que fazer a operação inversa que tinha feito para pegar o endereço de `X`, então tem que fazer o que se chama derreferenciar, que é feito com o operador `*`. O `*P` quer dizer "pegue o valor que está no endereço de `p`".

Coloquei um `(void *)` porque bons compiladores com a configuração correta impede a compilação direta, eles te obrigam ser explícito no que está usando para indicar que não está confundindo o que está mandando. Mas é possível não usar em certas circunstâncias (não usei no Coding Ground, olhe lá), sob risco de fazer algo errado em código real mais complexo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 2;
    int *p = &x;
    printf("O endereço de X e: %p\n", (void *)p);
    printf("O valor de X e: %d\n", *p);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/i6sMDw). E [no **repl.itd**](https://repl.it/join/fqkfxopx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/PrintPointer.c).

Veja mais em [Qual o significado do operador "&" (e comercial) na linguagem C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101) e [Operador & e * nas funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156278/101).

Answer (score 0):

```
int x=5;
int *p;
p = &x;
printf("O valor de X e: %d\n", *p);
printf("O valor de X e: %d\n", p);
```

O primeiro `printf()` imprime o valor de x, o segundo imprime o endereço do apontador.

Todo o seu codigo está bem, esse 'c' é 12 em hexadecimal.

Comment: Então a única coisa que mudou foi de `%p` para `%d`. Poderia explicar esta única alteração, visto que não descreveu na sua resposta?

Comment: O programa imprime o valor correto no codeblocks, alterei para `%d` e inicializei para poder ver de forma mais simples

Comment: Então basicamente mudou nada? Entendi menos ainda a resposta então :(

Comment: Eu assumi que não imprimia os valores que esperava, por isso editei o codigo daquela maneira para tentar acompanhar melhor, obviamente que se o erro for no compilador do codeblocks a minha resposta nao faz sentido

Comment: Em um compilador bem configurado isto não funciona, em um leniente não imprime um endereço de memória que é o desejado.