# Diferença entre vector de ponteiros para uma class e vector para uma class?

Tags: c++, classes, ponteiro, declaração-de-variável, vector

Quando é ponteiro para class teremos obrigatoriamente que alocar espaço memória? 
Qual é mesmo a diferença entre as duas seguintes declarações e quando devem ser usadas ?

```
Vector <class*> nameOfVector;
Vector <class> nameOfVector;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não necessariamente. Depende do que deseja, mas quase sempre será o caso.

A primeira espera um endereço de memória, então é isso que deve prover. Você pode fazer isso com:

- alguma coisa que já gere um ponteiro para você
- usar o operador [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) que aloca a memória
- usar a função [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc), embora não seja recomendado
- usar qualquer coisa que aloque memória
- usar uma [referência para um endereço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125793/101).

A leitura da primeira linha é

> Declare a variável `nameOfVector` que será do tipo vetor de ponteiros para objetos do tipo class

Se optar por pegar o endereço de algo já existente tem que tomar o cuidado para o tempo de vida deste objeto. Ele deve ter duração igual ou maior ao do vetor, sob pena de ocorrer um [*dangling pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Mas é raro haver uma situação que faça sentido fazer algo assim. Ou usa o próprio objeto, ou usa um ponteiro para uma área da memória alocada.

Note que se for alocar memória no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) (leia para entender a função de cada área da memória) e é sua responsabilidade gerenciar sua memória. É comum o uso de [ponteiros inteligentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) ([pergunta aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83886/101)), que é um pouco diferente do ponteiro bruto que foi usado.

Dê uma lida em [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101).

O segundo exemplo espera o próprio objete instanciado pelo tipo representado por `class` no exemplo (esse nome é reservado e não pode ser usado). Você deve copiar o objeto para dentro do vetor, não haverá referência para ele. Em geral só compensa fazer isto em objetos pequenos e [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).

A leitura da primeira linha é

> Declare a variável `nameOfVector` que será do tipo vetor de objetos do tipo class

Tem mais informações em [Como usar o vector para armazenar uma classe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120231/101).