# Alocar memória com ponteiro ou referência?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, memória, referência

Há alguma diferença significativa entre esses dois métodos?

```
MyClass &ref = (*(new MyClass));
MyClass *ptr = (new MyClass);
```

Comment: Não sei se seria duplicada mas [essa pergunta/resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56470/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-ponteiro-e-refer%C3%AAncia) pode ser útil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você mandar imprimir já vê uma diferença:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string &ref = *new string("teste");
    //string &ref2 = nullptr;
    string *ptr = new string("teste");
    cout << ref << endl;
    cout << ref.length() << endl;
    cout << ptr->length() << endl;
    cout << &ref << endl;
    cout << ptr;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ApFQKH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sjmdujci-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Pointer/Reference.cpp).

O ponteiro não é convertido automaticamente e o que está mandando fazer é imprimir seu valor, ou seja um endereço, e para pegar o dado efetivo não é algo tão simples.

Também pode ser observado que para acessar um membro pela referência usar-se o operador `.` e para o ponteiro usa-se o `->` que faz a derreferência automaticamente.

A referência está recebendo o valor da *string* e não um ponteiro, note que teve que fazer a derreferência, não está armazenando na variável sequer a mesma coisa, então a comparação é laranjas com bananas. E não sei se deveria aceitar, mas é fato que aceita.

Se falhar a alocação virá um nulo e uma referência não aceita valor nulo em, condições normais. Acho até algo que deveria ser proibido, então não use.

Uma referência é um `const *` e não pode ser mudado, um ponteiro é livre.

Não use ponteiros ou referências sem necessidade. Sei que esse é um exercício, mas neste caso foi sem necessidade. Se fosse fazer algo real jamais faria isso, então estamos avaliando algo que pode fazer, não que deve. Só use o que pode justificar.

Esse é um caso que só está disfarçando o uso de um ponteiro, porque o `new` devolve um ponteiro e não uma referência. Então não o use para isto. Referência são úteis quando são criadas por conta própria, quando o dado está na *stack*. Só porque funciona, não quer dizer que deve usar.

Veja mais em [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101). Também é útil: [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101). E ainda: [Em que realmente são usados ponteiros em C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175967/101).

Nem falei que é melhor [usar um *smart pointer*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120231/101) ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83886/101)) no lugar de ponteiro bruto.